# jQuery - Ajax POST method error,

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm experimenting with a simple AJAXing using jQuery. I'm posting an empty data to a .php page then echoing the JSON encoded data back to the page where my javascript is.

I'm getting an error while doing this but I can't figure out why this code is producing the error..

Here is the code I've written,

**index.php**

```
    <form id="getData">
        <button name="control" type="submit" value="A">GET DATA</button>
    </form>

    <form id="showData">
        <button name="control" type="submit" value="A">SHOW DATA</button>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#getData").submit(function(event){

            $.ajax({
                url : "/getVehiclePosition.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    //data - response from server
                    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                    $('#results').append(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    console.error(
                        "The following error occurred: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                }
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
```

in the Chrome console, I'm getting the following error..

```
The following error occurred: error 
error @ ?control=A:52
i @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
y @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:4
c @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:4
```

For some reason if I take out the form submit binding to #getDATA, it works well again.. pulling my hair out at the moment, please help!. Many thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]===================================================================
Captured XHR,

[image]

Comment: Try to have a look at your Developer Tools (F12) > Network and filter by XHR. Then you should see a red `getVehiclePosition.php` on the left after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't stop the form from submitting by its default action so that you can implement your ajax request. Use event.preventDefault() before your ajax.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
        $("#getData").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url : "/getVehiclePosition.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    //data - response from server
                    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                    $('#results').append(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    console.error(
                        "The following error occurred: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Oh wow, yes, you are absolutely right! What a silly mistake..works like a charm now, thanks alot!